# Incorrect Ikonli icons displayed

Tags: javafx

I am having problems using the Ikonli icon packs. I am creating FontIcon objects and then using those to set the graphics on buttons. Icons taken from the FontAwesome5 pack work great. Icons taken from the Material2 pack seem to shift somehow - for example, I try to get mdal-6_ft_apart but what actually gets displayed is mdal-loyalty. And no matter which Icon I load from MaterialDesign2, all I see is an empty box.

I'm running this through Eclipse, and everything looks fine when stepping through with the debugger. This is the value of the button graphic:

```
ObjectProperty [bean: mdal-6_ft_apart:15:0xffffffff, name: iconCode, value: MDAL_6_FT_APART]
```

and yet, on the screen, it's something completely different.

This is a Maven project using OpenJDK 16 and JavaFX 16.  I've tried loading just a single icon pack instead of all 3, but no difference. Also, there are never any errors retrieving the icons. The ServiceProviders are all found, and the icons are available.

I made a small Hello World program and everything runs fine, so it's definitely an issue with my program and not the library. But I have no idea what the problem is, and I've been staring at this for almost 2 hours. Has anyone come across this before? I'd appreciate any help, because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: don't see much we can do from here - you have to find the exact difference between the simple helloworld and your real project that's causing the havoc. Divide-and-conquer: break it up into parts until you find the piece that's misbehaving with the rest working fine ..

Comment: Which version of Ikonli are you using?

Comment: I'm using 12.2.0.  It's a very weird problem.  I've started peppering my application with little pop-up dialogs displaying an icon, and there's definitely a point at which the icon goes from correct to incorrect.  I'll report back when I've narrowed it down

Comment: @kleopatra I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask - if someone has encountered something like this already, they could save me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Answering this myself in case it saves someone else some time.  I was installing the Ikonli library in order to replace the FontAwesomeFX library that is no longer available.  I had gotten partway through replacing the icons when I ran the app in order to check the progress, and that's when I saw the errors.

The problem turned out to be an interference between the two libraries - FontAwesomeFX was throwing of Ikonli.  The icon shift didn't actually occur until the code displayed a FontAwesomeFX icon, which made it seem a little random depending on the order I would open the dialogs when testing.  I'm assuming an issue with the Service Handlers, though I'm not positive because I stopped troubleshooting once I realized the problem and just finished the replacement.

Once I stopped displaying FontAwesomeFX icons and the dependency was removed, Ikonli worked fine.